# Error after PyBrain installation: "No module named pybrain.tools.shortcuts"

Tags: python, pybrain

I have installed PyBrain using command prompt. How can I get it into use? I have Enthought Canopy as my Python environment, and I used import pybrain.tools.shortcuts, but I got the error "No module named pybrain.tools.shortcuts".
What do I have to do?

Comment: How are you actually installing PyBrain? It seems that the module hasn't been properly installed in your environment.

Comment: @AnotherCodingEnthusiast: I opened up the setup file in command prompt and typed python setup.py install
It got installed.